# Query works when form action is to same page, not when it redirects to another

Tags: mysql

I have query that gets data from a form, when the submit button is pressed the data should be stored in a database. When the form's action is *action="#"* the data is inputted into the database. But when the action is *action="otherPage.php"* the data is not inserted into the database. Any help ?

Side Note: I know the queries need to be changed to counter SQL injection this is just for testing

Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $name = $_POST['fullName'];

                $idNumber = $_POST['idNo'];
                $cardNo = $_POST['cardNo'];

                $_SESSION['fullName'] = $name;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $idNumber;

                $checkExists = "SELECT * FROM system.table WHERE idNumber = '$idNumber' ";
                $resExists = mysqli_query($connection,$checkExists)
                    or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($connection));

                if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($resExists) > 0)
                {
                    $updateCard = "UPDATE system.table SET cardNo = '$cardNo' WHERE idNumber=$idNumber"; 

                    $resUpdate= mysqli_query($connection,$updateCard)
                    or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($connection));
                }

                if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($resExists) < 1)
                {
                    $company = $_POST['company'];
                    $name = trim($name);
                    $last_name = (strpos($name, ' ') === false) ? '' : preg_replace('#.*\s([\w-]*)$#', '$1', $name);
                    $first_name = trim(preg_replace('#'.$last_name.'#', '', $name));  

                    $insert = "INSERT INTO system.table (idNumber,name,surname,company,cardNo) VALUES 
                        ('$idNumber','$first_name','$last_name','$company','$cardNo')";

                    $resInsert = mysqli_query($connection,$insert)
                    or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($connection));
                }



                $connection->close();
            }
```

Comment: is the php page and html page in the same directory???

Comment: Where is the PHP code? In which file

Comment: Yes, I have a file containing all the pages except index

Comment: @Salketer Sorry must have hit that tag by mistake. The code  is contained in a php tag.

Comment: @GeordeyGatt No, I meant the code you are showing us, in what file is it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the corrext way to go around it, but it works. I included `ob_start();` at the beginning of my code, left the action as

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="#">
```

Then included

```
header('Location:otherPage.php');
```

so that the page automatically redirects to *otherPage.php*

Answer (score 0):

If you have two files in the same folder, it should be working:

myFolder
- testForm.php
- testUpload.php

testForm.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="testUpload.php">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Form</legend>   
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

testUpload.php:

```
<?php
print($_POST['name']);
exit;
```

Do you have any Redirection Statements in the config of your Web Server (e.g. Apache httpd.conf)?

Comment: That's Exactly what i was thinking, but for some reason it won't work, so I tackled the problem as the answer I posted.

Comment: Do you use .htaccess to redirect requests?

Comment: No I haven't used that

Comment: Did you look at Apache\logs\error.log or Apache\logs\access.log? What does `error_reporting(-1);` return?